# HTML showing in iOS email client preview pane for transactional email

Tags: email, html, ios

I have run into the most headscratching scenario you could imagine.

**Background:**
For our SAAS company, we are firing off transactional welcome emails that are beautifully formatted and declare the doc type, etc... utilising MandrillApp as the transactional mail service.

**Problem:**
The issue we have encountered is that in iOS7, the HTML source for the email is showing under the preview section under the sender and timestamp.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Attempted removing doc type completely which resulted in all HTML being shown
- Changed Doc Type to HTML 5 from XHTML 1.0
- Added in a Preheader. Didn't work

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
    <body>  
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 0 20px">
                        <table width="830" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <p style="padding:30px 0 1px">
                                            <font face="Helvetica Neue, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="6" color="#323232" style="line-height:1;font-size:34px;font-weight:300">
                                                Some Text
                                            </font>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                      </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does the preview still look wrong if you fix your HTML, particularly in the tr I am showing below?

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
               <p style="padding:30px 0 1px">
                  <font face="Helvetica Neue, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="6" color="#323232" style="line-height:1;font-size:34px;font-weight:300">
                                            Some Text
                   </font>
                </p>
             </td>

        -- You're missing </tr> here --

      </tbody>
```

Or was that just an error in entering your question here?

Comment: Hi Nvuono, I believe that was just an error while stripping out the HTML. Thanks for your hawk like eyesight there.